# ¿Comó hacer una consulta con ajax-jquery tomado de dos tablas?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

Estoy intentando consultar un par de tablas referente a una biblioteca y retornar los datos en formato JSON para luego mostrar los datos en una tabla maquetada en HTML. **El** **Problema** **es** que el json me retorna **undefined** ya he hecho consultas tomando los datos en formato JSON pero este es especial y me cuesta, aclarare que la consulta me la hace bien desde php. Pondre el codigo de la consulta en **php**:

```
 <?php 
//$cota=$_POST["c"];
$cota="FGHDFHDFH";
include_once("../conexion.php");

//----CONSULTA DE VARIAS TABLAS POR 'INNER JOIN', ES PARA OBTENER UNA SOLA FILA----
$r=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `prestamo` INNER JOIN solicitantes ON prestamo.id_soli=solicitantes.id_solicitante INNER JOIN libro ON prestamo.cotlibr=libro.cotlibr INNER JOIN tipo_prestamo ON prestamo.id_tip_pre=tipo_prestamo.id_tip_pre  WHERE libro.cotlibr='$cota' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
$r_id=mysql_fetch_object($r);
//----FIN CONSULTA DE VARIAS TABLAS POR 'INNER JOIN'----


//----CONSULTA A DOS TABLAS QUE ES PARA OBTENER LOS NOMBRES DE VARIOS AUTORES DE UN LIBRO----
$b_autor=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM libro INNER JOIN detaauto ON libro.cotlibr=detaauto.cotlibr WHERE libro.cotlibr='$cota'") or die(mysql_error());

//----LA TABLA PARA OBTENER LOS AUTORES LOS RECORRO CON UN CICLO YA QUE EN ESTE CASO SON DOS AUTORES QUE TIENE UN LIBRO----
while($r_autor=mysql_fetch_array($b_autor))
{
    $autor=$r_autor["codauto"];

    $dato[]=array("autor"=>$autor);//----LOS ALMACENO EN UNA VARIABLE 'datos' QUE ES ARRAY----

}

//----LO OBTENIDO DE LA PRIMERA CONSULTA LO GUARDO TAMBIEN EN LA VARIABLE 'datos' ESTE NO LO RECORRO EN UN CICLO YA QUE LO DEVUELVE ES UN SOLA FILA----
$dato[]=array(
    "idtp"=>$r_id->id_tip_pre,
    "titulo"=>$r_id->titlibr,
    "cota"=>$r_id->cotlibr, 
    );
echo json_encode($dato); //----LO IMPRIMO Y CONVIERTO A FORMATO JSON---
 ?>
```

en **js**

```
$("#btn-libro").click(function(event) { //----SE GATILLA AL HACER CLICK EN UN BOTON---
        event.preventDefault();
        var cota=$("#cota").val(); //---OBTENGO EL VALOR DE UN CAMPO TEXT INPUT---
        $.ajax({
            url: 'proceso/pro_bus_pre.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {c:cota},
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, val) { //----UTILIZANDO '$.each' RECORRO EL ARREGLO PARA SACAR----
                                                //----CADA VALOR DE LO QUE ME ENVIA PHP EN ESTE CASO LOS AUTORES----
                 console.log("success "+ data.autor +" tirulo "+data.titulo); //---ARROJA 'undefined' DEL RESULTADO DE LA DOS CONSULTAS----
            });
            console.log(data.titulo); //---ARROJA 'undefined'----

        });

    });
```

en cuanto a php esto es lo que me imprime que me parece estar bien para lo que quiero hacer:

> [{"autor":"cvhcfghf"},{"autor":"ADELMO GENRO
>   FILHO"},{"idtp":"3","titulo":"EL SECRETO DE LA
>   PIRAMIDE","cota":"FGHDFHDFH"}]

este es el resultado que quiere imprimir al usuario donde se muestra los deos autes vinculados al unico libro que estoy consultando. esto es todo el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No existe la propiedad titulo en todos los Objetos del arreglo prueba usar esto.

```js
$("#btn-libro").click(function(event) { //----SE GATILLA AL HACER CLICK EN UN BOTON---
        event.preventDefault();
        var cota=$("#cota").val(); //---OBTENGO EL VALOR DE UN CAMPO TEXT INPUT---
        $.ajax({
            url: 'proceso/pro_bus_pre.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {c:cota},
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            for (var item of data) {
              console.log(item);
            }

        });

    });
```